# How to upload file in the local folder and add it to the database at the same time in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file specifically pdf docx and excel files inside my local folder named 'upload', How do I upload my file and at the same time it is stored inside the table of my database as well?

This is my 'upload-manager.php' file:

```
<?php
// Check if the form was submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Check if file was uploaded without errors
    if(isset($_FILES["file"]) && $_FILES["file"]["error"] == 0){
        $allowed = array("pdf" => "application/pdf", "xlsx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "xls" => "application/vnd.ms-excel", "docx" => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document");
        $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
        $type = $_FILES["file"]["type"];
        $size = $_FILES["file"]["size"];

    // Verify file extension
    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed)) die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

    // Verify file size - 50MB maximum
    $maxsize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;
    if($size > $maxsize) die("Error: File size is larger than the allowed limit.");

    // Verify MYME type of the file
    if(in_array($type, $allowed)){
        // Check whether file exists before uploading it
        if(file_exists("upload/" . $name)){
            echo $name . " is already exists.";
        } else{
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "upload/" . $name);
            echo "Your file was uploaded successfully.";
        } 
    } else{
        echo "Error: There was a problem uploading your file. Please try again."; 
    }
    } else{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
    }
}
?>
```

and this is the file-upload-form.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>File Upload Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload-manager.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h4>Upload File</h4>
        <label for="fileSelect">Filename:</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="fileSelect">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">
        <p><strong>Note:</strong> Only .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .png formats allowed to a max size of 50 MB.</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to run it with this block of code which adds it to the database?

```
if(isset($_POST['insert'])) 
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $Agency = $_POST['agency'];
    $FName = $_POST['filename'];
    $FType = $_POST['myselectbox'];
    $Date = $_POST['date'];

    // mysql query to insert data
    $pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO `caap_report`(`agency`, `filename`, `filetype`, `date`) VALUES (:Agency,:FName,:FType,:Date)";
    $pdoResult = $pdoConnect->prepare($pdoQuery);
    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(":Agency"=>$Agency,":FName"=>$FName,":FType"=>$FType, ":Date"=>$Date));
```

}

Comment: what `at the same time` requirement is for? why can't you just save then do your DB stuff in **one PHP script**?

Comment: upload the file in the local folder and add it to database 'at the same time', or I would just create two separate forms? one that upload file and one that store to database?

Comment: in one request you send one form at the time. other than that I still not sure what you really want to do and why. and where is this db here in all this